# I didn't find "ZipFile" class in the "System.IO.Compression" namespace

Tags: c#, zip

I can't use "Zipfile" class in the name space "System.IO.Compression" my code is :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest,true);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

the error is :

The name 'zipfile' does not exist in the current context

How I can solve it ?

Comment: see Rick Strahl's [.NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET 4.0](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You need an extra reference for this; the most convenient way to do this is via the NuGet package [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/)

```xml
<!-- Version here correct at time of writing, but please check for latest -->
<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" Version="4.3.0" />
```

If you are working on .NET Framework without NuGet, you need to add a dll reference to the assembly, "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" - and ensure you are using at least .NET 4.5 (since it doesn't exist in earlier frameworks).

For info, you can find the assembly and .NET version(s) [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx)

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 ... and I don't found this dll file

Comment: @MohamedKamal indeed, you won't do unless you use .NET 4.5, since it didn't exist until then; see the "Version Information" info - "Supported in: 4.5"

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm having the same error. I checked Visual Studio-->help-->About Microsoft Visual Studio, it shows with .NET version 4.5.51650. What should I check next?

Comment: @foxwendy check that your project is also set to use .NET 4.5 or higher (right click project name-->Properties-->Target framework on the Application tab)

Comment: sometimes you added the reference before so clean the solution and rebuild that maybe did the trick.

Comment: I didn't have the `FileSystem` reference. Only `System.IO.Compression`. Thanks. Odd that it requires a file that isn't in the class's namespace. It's an odd deviation from convention.

Comment: @ChrisBenard I found the same issue. Including a reference to System.IO.Compression was not enough, I needed FileSystem as well.  Interesting indeed.

Comment: Hello, found this very usefull today, just for those who may have trouble finding how to add it, In project properties, in the reference section, you add a new one, in the assemblies section, select framework and search for the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Comment: I should also mention that System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem should have the same version. The same problem occurs if not. I had two version of the dll (4.0.0.0 and 4.1.2.0) and accidently selected the wrong one.

Comment: No need to add the dll manually anymore. Just add the following NuGet package: System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

Answer (score 32):

For those who are green programmers in .NET, to add the DLL reference as [MarcGravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) noted, you follow these steps:

To add a reference in Visual C#

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
3. Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

From the MSDN Article, [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already had using System.IO.Compression; but then had to add a reference to using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem as you described above to get ZipFile to compile without the OP's original error.

Answer (score 18):

you can use an external package if you cant upgrade to 4.5. One such is Ionic.Zip.dll from DotNetZipLib.

```
using Ionic.Zip;
```

you can download it here, its free. http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: or install it through NuGet

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: his question was "how do I fix it?" and this is one way to fix it - since his version of .net didn't support it.

Comment: Sadly, upgrade is not a choice sometimes. Have an upvote.

Comment: This is relevant if you are writing to 2000 PCs that have XP installed and your program cannot do any installation (to install .net 4.5 framework)

Answer (score 14):

Just go to References and add "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem".

Comment: I have limitless places to find "References".  Can you give more hints as to where to find this?

Comment: @DanielKaplan you can fine Reference tab in the solution explorer below you project name, right click it and select add reference ones open expand the assemblies tab which will be at the top then scroll down and look for system.io.compression.filesystem and check it and click add at the bottom right.

Answer (score 4):

In solution explorer, right-click References, then click to expand assemblies, find System.IO.Compression.FileSystem and make sure it's checked.  Then you can use it in your class - `using System.IO.Compression;`

[Add Reference Assembly Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQlAc.png)

Answer (score 3):

A solution that helped me:
Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packaged for Solution... > Browse >
Search for System.IO.Compression.ZipFile and install it

Answer (score 2):

`System.IO.Compression` is now available as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression/) maintained by Microsoft.

To use `ZipFile` you need to download `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just cannot steer away from posting some useful info on this. I see the Zip question come up a lot and this answers nearlly most of the common questions.

To get around framework issues of using 4.5+... Their is a ZipStorer class created by jaime-olivares: https://github.com/jaime-olivares/zipstorer, he also has added an example of how to use this class as well and has also added an example of how to search for a specific filename as well.

And for reference on how to use this and iterate through for a certain file extension as example you could do this:

```
#region
/// <summary>
/// Custom Method - Check if 'string' has '.png' or '.PNG' extension.
/// </summary>
static bool HasPNGExtension(string filename)
{
    return Path.GetExtension(filename).Equals(".png", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        || Path.GetExtension(filename).Equals(".PNG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
#endregion

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //NOTE: I recommend you add path checking first here, added the below as example ONLY.
    string ZIPfileLocationHere = @"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\test.zip";
    string EXTRACTIONLocationHere = @"C:\Users\Name\Desktop";

    //Opens existing zip file.
    ZipStorer zip = ZipStorer.Open(ZIPfileLocationHere, FileAccess.Read);

    //Read all directory contents.
    List<ZipStorer.ZipFileEntry> dir = zip.ReadCentralDir();

    foreach (ZipStorer.ZipFileEntry entry in dir)
    {
        try
        {
            //If the files in the zip are "*.png or *.PNG" extract them.
            string path = Path.Combine(EXTRACTIONLocationHere, (entry.FilenameInZip));
            if (HasPNGExtension(path))
            {
                //Extract the file.
                zip.ExtractFile(entry, path);
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: The ZIP file is invalid or corrupted");
            continue;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: An unknown error ocurred while processing the ZIP file.");
            continue;
        }
    }
    zip.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add System.IO.Compression.ZipFile as nuget reference it is working

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you just Added the reference to System.IO.Compression it is missing the reference to System.IO.Compression.Filesystem.dll

And you need to do it on .net 4.5 or later (because it doesn't exist on older versions).

I just posted a script on TechNet Maybe somebody would find it useful it requires .net 4.5 or 4.7

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-a-Zip-file-from-a-b23a7530