# Zipping a stream on the fly without using the disk

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to write a method in my C# MVC project that streams a file from S3 (or anywhere) and compresses it into a zip file on-the-fly before sending the compressed stream to the user. So far I've found several ways to create a zip file from a stream by saving it to disk and then returning it normally, but I'd like to skip the saving to disk and use a buffer to stream approach. I'm trying to download  a very large file (4gb+) that is easily compressed to a fraction of its original size.

So far I have this which avoids the disk, but seems to load the entire file into memory first:

```
using( var memoryStream = new MemoryStream() )
{
    using( var archive = new ZipArchive( memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true ) )
    {
        var zipEntry = archive.CreateEntry( File );

        using( var entryStream = zipEntry.Open() )
        {
            S3.StreamFile( File, Bucket ).CopyTo( entryStream );
        }
    }

    return base.File( memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", File + ".zip" );
}
```

A similar question ([Creating a ZIP Archive in Memory Using System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17232414/292578)) only has answers that involve writing to disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a ZIP Archive in Memory Using System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression)

Comment: *but seems to load the entire file into memory first* - You mean `S3.StreamFile`?  What's your evidence for that?  [`Stream.CopyTo()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,295ec16c77d4fafb) uses a copy buffer size of `81920`.  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: You need to create a wrapper (Facade pattern) around a Stream object, that will track the stream position. Then you will not need any MemoryStream. Also you need to write to the output stream directly en return and EmptyResult

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ZipArchive class require a stream that provide the current position. `TrackablePositionStream` class below save the position by incrementing a field when a write call occurs

```
public class TrackablePositionStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;

    private long _position = 0;

    public TrackablePositionStream(Stream stream)
    {
        this._stream = stream;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        this._stream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        this._position += count;
        this._stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override bool CanRead => this._stream.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => this._stream.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => this._stream.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => this._stream.Length;

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this._position;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your action method :

```
using( var archive = new ZipArchive(new TrackablePositionStream(response.OutputStream), ZipArchiveMode.Create, true ) )
{
    var zipEntry = archive.CreateEntry( File );

    using(var entryStream = zipEntry.Open() )
    {
        S3.StreamFile( File, Bucket ).CopyTo( entryStream );
    }
}

return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: Great solution without using external libraries!! Works very well.

Comment: Why are we pulling `CanRead` and `CanSeek` from the underlying stream, when we know that we never support either of those? Shouldn't we return a constant `false` instead?

Comment: Because this is what is used by ZipArchive to know if it can use Position property or not.