# C# Create .Zip file without using Temp or change Tempfolder

Tags: c#

I try to create an .Zip File with C# without using the Tempfolder or change the Temp folder before create.

Normally I would build this scenario in Powershell but this time we need an C# code, cuz the old Windows machines wont have Powershell greater then v1...

Attached my code... Im very sure there are many improvements to make but it would be enough if I could create an .Zip without Temp or chaging Temp before.

```
        // Umgebungsvariable abfragen
        value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
        value1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");

        if (value == "D:\\ZipTemp" & value1 == "D:\\ZipTemp")
        {
            value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
            Console.WriteLine("Die Umgebungsvariable zeigt schon auf den richtigen Pfad");
            Console.WriteLine("Die Umgebungsvariable heißt {0}", value);
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", "D:\\ZipTemp");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", "D:\\ZipTEMP");
            value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
            _ = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");
            Console.WriteLine("Die Umgebungsvariable heißt {0}", value);
            Console.WriteLine("Die Umgebungsvariable heißt {0}", value);
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a ZIP Archive in Memory Using System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression)

Comment: "I try to create an .Zip File with C# without using the Tempfolder or change the Temp folder before create." **Why?**

Comment: @IanKemp we are using FBWF and temp isnt excluded. So we got problems while creating .Zip files that the FBWF throws an error and the .zip file cannot be created

Comment: @DragandDrop no sorry this is not the right way to solve this problem. Thx

Comment: If you got an exception, you'd better put it including the stack in your question.