# Powershell create a ZIP file with different folder attributes

Tags: powershell

I'm using a PowerShell script to create a zip file from a folder, specifically take a subfolder an a file and put them into a ZIP archive. However what I've noticed opening the archive with 7zip is that the folder doesn't have the `Store` method (the `D` attribute), while if I create the ZIP manually it does.

Since the ZIP file is for a Minecraft Datapack this results in the pack not being recognized by the game (unless I do the ZIP manually as I said).

This is the script I'm using

```
#Variables
$VERSION = "5.0"
$MC_VERSION = "1.20.2"
$NAME = "snow_on_stairs"
$DATA_PACK_FOLDER = "datapack"
$PACK_EXTENSION = "v"+$VERSION+"-"+$MC_VERSION+".zip"
$DATA_PACK_PATH = ".\"+$NAME+"-"+$DATA_PACK_FOLDER+"-"+$PACK_EXTENSION

#Create data pack
Compress-Archive -Path $(".\"+$DATA_PACK_FOLDER+"\*") -DestinationPath $DATA_PACK_PATH
```

The folder structure is this

```
RootFolder
 |
 +-- build.ps1
 |    
 +-- datapack
 |  |  
 |  +-- pack.mcmeta
 |  |
 |  +-- data
 |  |
 |  +-- ...
```

And I run `build.ps1` from the root folder.

This is the generated archive when I open it with 7zip
[image: Generated ZIP file]

And this is the manually created archive
[image: Manually created ZIP file]

As you can see, while the content is the same, the `Method` for the `data` folder is not, which when missing will cause the pack to not being recognized by the game.

Do I need to provide something to the `Compress-Archive` command in order to set this attribute?

Comment: How about using 7zip command line to create an archive? `7z a filename.zip` should do the trick

Comment: A while back I created [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332967/4190564) for reading a zip file using 7zip from PowerShell code.  In theory, the first 4 steps listed would be the same if you want to create a zip file using 7zip from PowerShell code.  I'm unable to find docs, but here is the [source file](https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp/blob/dev/SevenZip/SevenZipCompressor.cs).  CompressDirectory takes a directory path, either an archive name or archive stream, and optionally a password, search pattern and a flag indicating recursion.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. `Compress-Archive` produces a zip file where subdirectories display the `Stored` method, not an empty value. Is a PS console, try the following: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression ; Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. And then, with the paths to the zip files stored in `$zip1` and `$zip2`, compare the entries in each file using `$zip1, $zip2 | %{[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($_).Entries | Out-GridView}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [n0rd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31782/n0rd) said in a comment using the 7zip command did the trick!

I had to change the `Compress-Archive` command to this

`7z a datapack.zip \datapack\* pack.png`

So essentially I had to specify fisrt the archive file name and then the paths to all the folders and files that I have to put in.

One thing to mention is that initially the 7z command was not recognized and I had to add the 7zip installation folder to the environment PATH variable.

Comment: 7z multithreads too, well with .7z files...