# ZipArchive with in memory data dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to create a Zip Archive in C# with data that is created in memory. However every time I try to finally save the archive to disk it is empty. Right now I am testing with one file but it will end up being a list of files that will get archived.

```
var data = new Data
{
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName"
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
using var file = new MemoryStream(bytes);

using var archiveStream = new MemoryStream();
var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

var archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("data.json", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
using var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open();
file.CopyTo(entryStream);

using var fileStream = new FileStream("/Path/To/File/test.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
archiveStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to be efficient you should: 1) serialize directly to the entryStream, most serialization libraries have methods that handles streams. 2) Create the zip-archive using the fileStream. Neither of the memory streams adds anything unless you need the data as a byte array for some reason that you are not showing.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JonasH This is just testing in a console app. The data will be in an api call and returned in a response. There will be no real disk to write to. I am only writing for testing purposes.

Comment: @JonasH not sure if it is possible to write directly to the entry stream. I would love to see your example if you have one.

Comment: It does but that is what I am already doing. I thought you were suggesting when converting to json doing it directly to the entry stream.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm suggesting. See [Can I serialize json to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17939367/14918126 the problem is that `archiveStream` needs to be disposed before you can use it.
And you should set the position of the `archiveStream` to the start before copy it to the fileStream.
Following solution should work:

```cs
        var data = new Data
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName",
            LastName = "LastName"
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        using var file = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        using var archiveStream = new MemoryStream();
        var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

        var archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("data.json", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        using var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open();
        file.CopyTo(entryStream);
        archive.Dispose();

        using var fileStream = new FileStream("./test2.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        archiveStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        archiveStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did see that post but most of the answers didn't  show the Dispose. I must have missed it. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go back to the beginning of the memory stream once you have written into it.

```cs
archiveStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
archiveStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```