# How to Zip before Dowload a file/folder using Google.Drive.apis.V3?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I have a function that download folder and subfolder/file from Google Drive to my computer. But the function only download a file/folder a time. I want to Zip it on Google Drive and then download it(Just like how Google Drive web work when you download a folder or multiple file). Is there a way to do this using Google.drive.apis.v3?

Here's my Download Folder function using C#.

```
public void DownloadFolder(DriveService service, string folderId, string folderPath)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    var fileListRequest = service.Files.List();
    fileListRequest.Q = $"'{folderId}' in parents";
    fileListRequest.Fields = "files(id, name, mimeType)";
    var fileList = fileListRequest.Execute();

    // Dowload file/Folder
    foreach (var file in fileList.Files)
    {
        Container contain = new Container(file.Name, file.Id, file.MimeType, this.userName, this.location);
        listOfFiles.Add(contain);
        if (file.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
        {
            // Recursive if obj(file) is a folder.
            string subfolderPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, file.Name);
            DownloadFolder(service, file.Id, subfolderPath);
        }
        else
        {
            // if obj(file) is a normal file, download.
            string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, file.Name);
            DownloadFile(service, file.Id, filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a ZIP archive in memory using System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression)

Comment: @Charlieface read the question again this does not help them at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google drive API doesn't offer that kind of functionality you need to download the files one at a time and then zip them locally

Comment: How do you get around the inevitable rate-limit? Seems like no solution for downloading folders over 50 files programmatically.

Comment: Slow down your application run a sleep every now and then.  rate limit is there to prevent you flooding the system.

Comment: That's not really a robust solution. It'll take days to download a large folder. The rate limit wouldn't need to be there if google just had a zip / bulk download method

Comment: A robust solution for what?  Google drive is not a file hosting service.